# Is there any free EMF->SVG converter or plugin to Enterprise Architect which can export image as SVG?

Tags: svg, enterprise-architect, .emf

Unfortunately my Enterprise Architect 7.5 does not export in SVG, only in EMF (if I want vector format). I haven't been able to find any free converter which converts EMF to SVG. Do you know any?
Other possible solution might be some plugin to Enterprise Architect which provides such a feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem.
As a work around I print ea diagrams to pdf creator. This pdf I import in inkscape and save it as svg.

Answer (score 0):

I used [UCanCode](http://www.ucancode.net/Convert_EMF_TO_SVG.htm) ,however it has several bugs in win7.

Comment: Sorry about that~~That software really can not help.